# Bad Request Error with flask, python, HTML, unusual initialization behavior with flask.request.form

Tags: python, html, flask, bad-request

I'm writing a web-app using flask, python and HTML.  My issue is that the first time I load the a webpage, I get the following error

> Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server
>   could not understand.

I'm able to get the page to load eventually by "tricking" first running it without any `flask.request.form` calls, and then putting them back in (details below).  Something must be going wrong in my initialization. I'm new to `flask` and using `python` with `HTML`.

Assume I'm working from a directory called `example`. I have a python script called `test.py` and an HTML template called `test.html` with the following directory structure:

```
\example\test.py
\example\templates\test.html
```

My python script `test.py` is:

```python
import sys
import flask, flask.views
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "bacon"

class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        result = flask.request.form['result']
        return flask.render_template('test.html', result=result)
#       return flask.render_template('test.html')
    def post(self):
        return self.get()

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=View.as_view('main'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

and my HTML in `test.html` is

```HTML
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            Enter something into the box:
            <input type="text" name="result"/><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Execute!"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Steps to reproduce the error**

1: Run the `test.py` script, and open up the URL in a browser

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

You should see the following error

> Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server
>   could not understand.

2: Comment out the first 2 lines of the `def get(self)` function and uncomment the 3rd line of the `def get(self)` function so that `test.py` looks like this

```python
import sys
import flask, flask.views
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "bacon"

class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
#       result = flask.request.form['result']
#       return flask.render_template('test.html', result=result)
        return flask.render_template('test.html')
    def post(self):
        return self.get()

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=View.as_view('main'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

3: Refresh the URL, and you will see that things work (though I ultimately want to be able to return the value of `result`

4: Now, switch the lines that are commented out again. I.e, uncomment the first 2 lines of the `def get(self)` function and comment out the 3rd line of the `def get(self)` function so that `test.py` looks like this

```python
import sys
import flask, flask.views
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "bacon"

class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        result = flask.request.form['result']
        return flask.render_template('test.html', result=result)
#       return flask.render_template('test.html')
    def post(self):
        return self.get()

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=View.as_view('main'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

5: Refresh the URL and now you see things will be working as desired.

This is just a toy example illustrating the real problem exhibiting this weird behavior of how I have to "trick" my browser into showing me this webpage.  The

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The issue here is that you are attempting to access `POST`ed variables in a method that will only handle `GET` requests.  When you attempt to access a query string or POST parameter that is not set [Flask will, by default, raise a `BadRequest` error](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object) (because you are asking for something that the person hitting the page did not supply).

> What happens if the key does not exist in the form attribute? In that case a special KeyError is raised. You can catch it like a standard KeyError but if you don’t do that, a HTTP 400 Bad Request error page is shown instead. So for many situations you don’t have to deal with that problem.

If you need to access a variable from either `request.args` (GET) or `request.form` (POST) and you don't *need* it to be set use the `get` method to get the value if it is there (or `None` if it is not set.

```
# Will default to None
your_var = request.form.get("some_key")

# Alternately:
your_var = request.form.get("some_key", "alternate_default_value")
```

Here's an alternate way of structuring your code:

```
import sys
import flask, flask.views

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "bacon"
app.debug = True


class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        """Enable user to provide us with input"""
        return self._default_actions()

    def post(self):
        """Map user input to our program's inputs - display errors if required"""
        result = flask.request.form['result']
        # Alternately, if `result` is not *required*
        # result = flask.request.form.get("result")
        return self._default_actions(result=result)

    def _default_actions(self, result=None):
        """Deal with the meat of the matter, taking in whatever params we need
        to get or process our information"""
        if result is None:
            return flask.render_template("test.html")
        else:
            return flask.render_template("test.html", result=result)

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=View.as_view('main'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: This is a great explanation on how to implement default request values in Flask.  Thank you.

Comment: I am running the Flask app on an Apache server. No matter what I do, I get a bad request error. 'The browser sent a response' etc. Is it something to do with my server?

Comment: @Rutwick - worth asking a separate question with a minimal example that re-produces the issue.

Comment: nice `secret key`.